# How to trigger an input event in a text area with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, bots

I am making a script for LinkedIn, it consists of a few clicks and pastes a message but when the script pastes the message with the text in a textarea, it appears that the pasted message in the textarea and when it clicks in the button send, it sends an empty string, but if I manually click the textarea before click send and after being pasted automatically it sends the custom message, so I think that is I can trigger the input event of the textarea to update its value can send the message automatically.

Also the button send is disable before I update the textarea manually, so my workaround is to enable it by the command:

```js
selected = document.querySelector("[aria-label='Send invitation']");
selected.disabled = false;
```

Here is the source code, it's just a file of 20 lines of code.

```js
     function() {
        var selected;

        selected = document.querySelector(".pv-s-profile-actions");
        selected.click();
        selected = document.querySelector("[aria-label='Add a note']");
        selected.click();

        selected = document.querySelector('textarea[name="message"]')
        selected.value = 'Custom message.';
        if(selected == null){
            selected.disabled = false;
            selected.click();
        } else {
            selected = document.querySelector("[aria-label='Done']");
            selected.disabled = false;
            selected.click();
        }
    }
```

You can try in the console on a page of a LinkedIn profile that you aren't connected to.

I tried to use innerHTML but didn't work for me.
or function selected.dispatchEvent(new Event("input")); or selected.trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

I just need to use selected.focus(); before changing the text.

Edit: This worked for me before, but now I am with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

try like below, you will be able to send a message

```
var msgInput = document.querySelector('.relative > textarea[name="message"]')
if(msgInput) {
    message = "Hello"
    msgInput.value = message
}
var doneBtn = document.querySelector('.artdeco-modal__actionbar > button[aria-label="Done"]')
if(doneBtn) {
    doneBtn.disabled = false;
    doneBtn.click();
}
```